# Return and access java object/class from jni

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a Java method which returns a instance of object/class 'Readcommpacket'. The call to the Java method is initiated from the NDK/JNI side(c++ -> java-> return-> java object-> c++). How do I complete this, I'm struggling with the proper JNI calls/signatures to complete this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Java object/class used as a return.

```
public class ReadCommPacket {

    public byte[] RCPbtyeread;
    public int RCPbytecount;

    public ReadCommPacket(byte[] btyeread, int bytecount){
        this.RCPbtyeread = btyeread;
        this.RCPbytecount = bytecount;
    }
}
```

Java method called by JNI

```
public ReadCommPacket BTMsgToNDKComm(){
        if(bluetoothConnectedRunnable != null){
            return bluetoothConnectedRunnable.readBT();//returns ReadCommPacket obj
        }
        return new ReadCommPacket(null, -1);
}
```

JNI/NDK c/c++ code

```
void recvFromBlueTooth(char * recvdByte){

JniMethodInfo methodInfo;
if (! getMethodInfo(&methodInfo, "BTMsgToNDKComm", "V"))//what signature would I use?
{
    LOGD("Cannot find method!");
    return;
}

//retreive btye[] and int from Readcommpacket here. What JNI calls?

}
```

Comment: You can find the signatures by running `javap -s` on the Java class.

Comment: The official JNI documentation is pretty good if you just take it calmly at your own pace. And it is very important to understand it thoroughly. One warning: a lot of JNI typedefs come down to `void *` and so the compiler will not warn if you mix them up. When you say “How do I complete this” you are rather unspecific and risk making it sound as though you want us to do your work.

Comment: You seem to be using `getMethodInfo` (meant for .Net methods) to inquire about a Java method. You need `(*env)->getMethodID` – just read the manual!

Answer (score 0):

signature contains package name.

let’s suppose package name is com.example

then signature in your example will be:

```
()Lcom/example/ReadCommPacket
```

P.S. if you call this method from c++, make sure class name & method name will not be obfuscated by pro guard (if you use it)

---

Answer (score 0):

Run the command `javap -s classname.class`
The output will have the descriptor that you can use as it is Including ";"

For example: `javap -s abc.class`

Trying to return an instance of abc

```
Public static com.getInstance();
    descriptor: **()Lcom;**

public int init(java.lang.String, java.lang.String);
    descriptor: **(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I**
```